# Is it possible to update package.json attribute from terminal?

Tags: json, package.json, npm-scripts

In my package.json file I have some attributes defined (mainly pay attention to 'ticket'):

```json
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "buildDate": "20200124",
  "author": "John Doe <john@doe.net>",
  "ticket": "JIRA-123",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "start": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
 ...
}
```

My question: is it possible to update attributes that lives in package.json from terminal? For example, before running npm build command, the prompt would appear asking to enter the ticket number you're working on.

Please enter the ticket number:

User enters JIRA-12345.

Package json should update like this:

```json
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "buildDate": "20200124",
  "author": "John Doe <john@doe.net>",
  "ticket": "JIRA-12345",
  ....
```

Is it possible to achieve this? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, npm has no built-in feature to achieve your requirement. However it is possible using a custom solution. Consider the following approach:

- Writing a custom node.js script, *(as per *prompt.js* provided below)*, that utilizes:

  - the node.js builtin [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module to create an interface for prompting the user to enter a ticket number.
  - the node.js builtin [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) method for updating the *package.json* with the new ticket number.
- To automatically invoke the process of prompting the user for a ticket number, (i.e. before running the `build` npm script), utilize a [npm pre script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts#pre--post-scripts) in the `scripts` section of your *package.json*. Further information about pre hooks can be found in [this article](https://medium.com/yld-blog/using-npm-pre-and-post-hooks-d89dcf2d86cf).

---

#### Solution:

The following steps describe how to achieve your requirement:

1. Create a node.js script as follows:

   **prompt.js**

   ```js
   const readline = require('readline');
   const { writeFile } = require('fs');

   const pkgJsonFile = './package.json';
   const pkgJsonData = require(pkgJsonFile);

   const rl = readline.createInterface({
     input: process.stdin,
     output: process.stdout
   });

   function updatePackageJson(ticketNumber) {
     pkgJsonData.ticket = ticketNumber;
     const newPkgJsonData = JSON.stringify(pkgJsonData, null, 2) + '\n';

     writeFile(pkgJsonFile, newPkgJsonData, 'utf8', writeFileError => {
       if (writeFileError) throw writeFileError;
     });
   }

   rl.question('Please enter the ticket number: ', ticketNumber => {
     rl.close();
     updatePackageJson(ticketNumber);
   });

   rl.on('SIGINT', () => {
     console.log('\nAborting ...');
     process.exit(1);
   });
   ```

   Let's save `prompt.js` in the root of your project directory, at the same level as where *package.json* resides:

   ```
   my-project
   ├── ...
   ├── node_modules
   │   └── ...
   ├── package.json
   └── prompt.js        <----
   ```
2. Next define the *`pre`* script in the `scripts` section of your *package.json* file named `prebuild`:

   **package.json**

   ```json
   ...
   "scripts": {
     ...
     "prebuild": "node prompt.js",      // <----
     "build": "node build/build.js",
   },
   ...
   ```

#### Running:

When you next run the following command:

```
npm run build
```

the following message prompt will appear in the terminal:

> `Please enter the ticket number:`

After entering a ticket number the `"ticket"` entry in *package.json* is updated with the new values, e.g. *"JIRA-123"*. Subsequently the `build` npm script runs.